# how indexes are stored in elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I had certain question regarding elasticsearch but unable to find appropriate answer:

How indexes are  stored in Elasticsearch. At which folder location they are stored.

Is it possible to store at different location.

What does this mean  " **localhost:9200/path1/path2** "

On which algorithm indexing is done in elasticsearch.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- Indexes are stored on disk as configured in [`elasticsearch.yml` with the configuration option `path.data`](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/setup/configuration/);
- localhost on port 9200 is the default connection port for the [HTTP REST interface](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/), the path of the url generally defines an action to be taken (like searching for documents);
- What exactly do you mean with the algorithm? Elasticsearch is a search engine, it uses [Lucene](https://lucene.apache.org/) to read documents and index their properties to enable search.

To be fair, all of this is available in the documentation for elasticsearch.

Comment: Elasticsearch is based on lucene. So it uses lucene algorithm for indexing or they had different.

Comment: The indexes as stored on disk are usable as Lucene indexes. That is: they are searchable by a Lucene-powered application (like Luke) even outside of elasticsearch. The way in which Lucene does this is documented by Lucene.

Comment: the path which we give after localhost:9200 what does it represent.Do that path can be seen aas directory

Comment: Please click on the link in my answer, it will take you to the documentation. All of this really is available on elasticsearch's website.

Comment: That describe for representation of node or cluster.
But if i had single node than what does that path mean

Comment: Dear sir, please click on some of the links on the right hand side of that page in stead of asking SO to explain a documentation resource to you. The path in the url follows the REST pattern, it defines actions on resources. It has nothing to do with a path on your hard drive.